# How to get status of Service Application?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, powershell

Is it possible to get the status of the Service Applications of SharePoint without visiting the SharePoint Administrative Center?

On using the `Get-SPServiceApplication` , Powershell returns a list of Service Applications along with their GUID. Is there any way to check the status of these service applications via Powershell or C#?

I found that some of these Service Applications are visible in the IIS Manager under `SharePoint Web Services` but not all of them are there.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the status of these service applications via Powershell

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | select displayname,status
```

To show all properties directly, try to use [Format Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view) to Change `Output View` as below.

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | Format-List
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I had one question though, why does `Get-SPServiceApplication` not show the status directly? I mean if I run it simply without any `select` it shows me with only 3 fields i.e. Displayname, ID & Typename.

Comment: Great to hear it's helped you, regarding your comment, i have updated my answer kindly check it, and don;t hesitate to tell us if you need more clarification.  please if it helped you Upvote/Mark as an answer :) thanks!

Comment: It's shocking though that the official Microsoft Documentation does not mention this - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607913.aspx

Sorry but I just got started with SharePoint so it is tough for me even if it is basic :)